# Why payment gateway service can only get access from my web application domain name?

Tags: service

In my site I have payment service. when i was trying to access it from VS it was not working because URL was not as registers.

once i have hosted site on server and I have made request from the registered URL It has started working and i can access it.

My query is how they can restrict their service to my domain name ?

Answer (score 0):

They have probably restricted it by IP address.